# In Typescript, why am I required to set the property of a class that is defined as read-only?

Tags: typescript

I have the following class definition:

```
class Department
{
    name: string;
    id: string;

    get prefix(): string
    {
        return  !isNaN(parseFloat(this.id)) ? "n" : "i" ;
    }
}
```

Elsewhere in my code, I try to use it like this:

```
getDepartmentList(): Department[] {
    return [
        {
            "name": "Dept 1",
            "id": "1000"
        }
    ];
}
```

However, I get the following error:

> Type '{ "name": string; "id": string; }' is not assignable to type
>   'Department'. Property 'prefix' is missing in type '{ "name": string;
>   "id": string; }'.

I am sure the real problem is my lack of understanding of Typescript, but can someone explain why the compiler sees the getter function as a property and expects me to set a value on it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your class Department is creating a type Department. You are defining that to contain `name`, `id` and `prefix`. The objects you return in `getDepartmentList` does not contain the `prefix`, so they are not structurally compatible with the type Department. Hence you get an error.

I guess that you assume that the `prefix`-property will be available on anything do declare to be of the type Department. This is not the case, there is no kind of dynamic class assignments like that in typescript. You have to make sure yourself that objects that you say is certain type, actually fulfill that type.

You could do it something like this:

```
class Department
{
    constructor(public name:string, public id:string){ }

    get prefix(): string
    {
        return  !isNaN(parseFloat(this.id)) ? "n" : "i" ;
    }
}

function getDepartmentList(): Department[]
{
    return [new Department("Dept 1", "1000")];
}
```

Here you are instantiating new objects from the Department class, hence those objects will all have the prefix property.

The use of the access modifier in the constructor signature is telling typescript to create a property of that parameter, instead of only being treated as an argument.

It's equivalent to:

```
class Department
{
    name: string;
    id:string;

    constructor(name:string, id:string){
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }

    get prefix(): string
    {
        return  !isNaN(parseFloat(this.id)) ? "n" : "i" ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Alex! I guess my confusion came from the fact that I viewed `prefix` as a function, not a property, hence I did not expect I'd have to assign it at instantiation.

Comment: Even if it was a normal function, you would still have to make sure it exists on the objects that you say are of the type Department since it will be declared to be a part of the Department-type, following your pattern here.

Comment: Got it. Even though for someone who's done c# development for the past few years this seems totally unintuitive.

Comment: You'll get the hang of it :) Think of it like this: All your type definitions are just for the static type checking and there is nothing that happens to the generated code when you declare a variable or the return value of a function to be of that or this type. Your `getDepartmentList` is not going to have a trace of Department in it or what it returns. So what will happen when you try to access `prefix` on a object of `{"name": "Dept 1", "id": "1000"}`? It's always going to be undefined.

Comment: What still escapes me though is how will my `prefix` variable be readonly in this case? I need its values to always be derived from the other properties -- is there a better way to accomplish that?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what problem you have. Are you afraid of someone overwriting the prefix property in your object? In TS 2.0, you can use the new `readonly` keyword to prevent that, i'm not sure you can combine it with getters/setters, but you could always make it a regular method in that case.

Comment: @July.Tech Apparently **A property declared with a get accessor and no set accessor is considered read-only.**: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#read-only-properties-and-index-signatures (TS 2.0)

Comment: Yes, that's what I thought, but as it is now Typescript has no problem with me doing this: `{
            "name": "Dept 1",
            "id": "1000",
            "prefix": "whatever"

        }`

Comment: Yes, that's because that object is structurally compatible with the type of Department. This is the nature of structural typing in TS, the compiler does not care about the underlying nature of `prefix`, it only cares about that that it's there and that it's a string. I'm not sure you can avoid it, but if you *really* don't want to trust the object here, you could always move out the prefix-logic to some place safe.

Comment: I'll try to clean up these comments tomorrow and put them into the question/answer instead if you don't mind.

Comment: Of course I don't mind! Your answers have been very helpful to me, so I am sure they will be as helpful to someone else in a similar situation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Putting a get in front of your method is all good and dandy, but what if my method requires a parameter?